# how can you search a rails 3 record created_at on a specific week?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
Ticket.all(:conditions => ['week(created_at) = ?', 25])
```

works in rails console.  but does not work in the rails model.

How do I change the code so it works in the Ticket model?

Also, is there a way to make it an instance method so I can search only records of that instance:

```
tickets = john.tickets.on_week(25).all
```

Comment: Please demonstrate how you're using this in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :on_week, lambda{|week_no| where("week(created_at) = ?",week_no)}
end
```

However, i'm not sure if week function will work with Postgres but since it's working for you on the console, i assume you're not using that database.

Also it would be easier to help if you showed how you were calling the model like @Ryan Bigg commented.